# How to find which element is being repeated the most in group by in Pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data fram which is grouped by year and by genres

```
new_df=df1.groupby(['release_year','genres'])['release_year','genres','budget_adj']
```

`new_df.info()`

my current table is like

```
                    release_year    genres  budget_adj
                    count   count   count
release_year    genres          
1960            Action  7   7   7
              Adventure 5   5   5
                Comedy  7   7   7
                Crime   2   2   2
1961            Action  7   7   7
              Adventure 6   6   6
              Animation 1   1   1
              Comedy    8   8   8
```

and so on

I want to find which genres was most produced in each year how can I write a pandas query for this??

Comment: @NagaKiran does this help

Comment: What if the max is a tie like in 1960 [Action, comedy]? Return both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could something like this:

```
df.loc[df.loc[:,('genres','count')].groupby(level=0)
                                   .rank(ascending=False, method='dense')
                                   .loc[lambda x: x==1].index]
```

Output:

```
            release_year genres budget_adt
                   count  count      count
1960 Action            7      7          7
     Comedy            7      7          7
1961 Comedy            8      8          8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
df.reset_index().groupby(['genres']).apply(lambda x: x[x.genres_count == x.genres_count.max()])
```

Out:

```
                Brand   Metric   release_year_count genres_count    budget_adj_count
Brand                       
1960      0      1960   Action  7   7   7
          2      1960   Comedy  7   7   7
1961      7      1961   Crime   8   8   8
```